# How to enable networking in vmware 17 player and debian 13 testing with kernel 6.3.0-1-amd64

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, kernel

I have installed "***VMware-Player-Full-17.0.2-21581411.x86_64***" on Debian 13 trixie (testing) with kernel "***6.3.0-1-amd64***" according https://wiki.debian.org/VMware#VMware_Workstation_Pro.2FPlayer_17

i installed vmnet and vmmon modules by hand as root

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source  
tar xvf vmnet.tar  
cd vmnet-only  
make  
cd ..  
tar xvf vmmon.tar  
cd vmmon-only  
make  
cd ..  
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/misc/vmmon.ko  
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/misc/vmnet.ko  
depmod -a  
service vmware restart
```

The final command freezes, ***service vmware restart***

I also tried the command

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

and i get these errors

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
modprobe: FATAL: Module vmnet is in use.
rmmod: ERROR: Module vmnet is in use
Unable to stop services
```

If i try to unload vmnet module from the kernel i get these

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo modprobe -r vmnet
modprobe: FATAL: Module vmnet is in use.
```

1. How to stop vmnet from being in use and install again vmware modules with

   sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

?

2. In my vmware machines i do not have networking nor NAT nor Bridged due to vmnet freeze

3)dmesg gives:

```
sudo dmesg | grep vmnet
[    8.856687] traps: Missing ENDBR: init_module+0x0/0x110 [vmnet]

[    8.856760] RIP: 0010:init_module+0x0/0x110 [vmnet]

[    8.856774]  ? __pfx_init_module+0x10/0x10 [vmnet]

[    8.856779]  ? __pfx_init_module+0x10/0x10 [vmnet]

[    8.856818] Modules linked in: vmnet(OE+) 
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci vmmon(OE) ccm cmac 
algif_hash 
algif_skcipher af_alg qrtr bnep binfmt_misc nls_ascii nls_cp437 
vfat 
fat snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common 
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_hdmi 
snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo snd_hda_codec_generic 
videobuf2_vmalloc uvc videobuf2_memops ledtrig_audio 
videobuf2_v4l2 
videodev snd_soc_dmic videobuf2_common snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl mc 
iwlmvm snd_sof_intel_hda_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal 
intel_powerclamp 
soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence 
coretemp btusb snd_sof_intel_hda btrtl kvm_intel snd_sof_pci 
btbcm 
mac80211 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp btintel btmtk kvm snd_sof bluetooth 
libarc4 snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core irqbypass 
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ghash_clmulni_intel iwlwifi 
snd_soc_core aesni_intel snd_compress jitterentropy_rng 
soundwire_bus 
crypto_simd cryptd cfg80211 snd_hda_intel sha512_ssse3 
snd_intel_dspcfg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

i download kernel 5.15.120 and buid it from scratch on Debian 13 trixie testing.

When i boot kernel 5.15.120 and run vmware, it compiles the vmmon and vmnet modules without complain.

It was kernel issue of 6.x series